# FreePie forgot how to do division

Tags: windows-7

I've been using this program for a long time with no issues.  But yesterday it abruptly forgot how to do division.  Almost every equation started return 0, while a few returned 1 or -1.  I have no idea what the pattern is.

I even tried typing the code "diagnostics.watch( 1 / 2 )" which should of course return 0.5, but it returns 0.

I tried uninstalling FreePie and installing it again, but that didn't fix it.

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Do variables need to be declared with a type? Did you use an integer type rather than a floating point type? Would this be better suited to Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Attie I wasn't sure about whether it should be on SO myself.  It appears to be installable software, though.

Comment: This appears to be on-topic here, it's about the operation of the software.  But Attie's suggestion of providing a MCVE is always good advice so that readers can reproduce the problem, understand the exact issue, and verify that their solution works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the program is doing a couple of things without letting you know it's doing them.

In traditional integer division, 1/2 is zero, because that operation is trying to store the value back into an integer.  0.5 is not a valid integer value, so it's storing it as 0.

The other operations (yielding -1 and 1) seem to be doing the floating point arithmetic okay, but they are doing an integer "ceiling" operation on positive values less than 1 (any floating point value gets rounded *up* to the next integer value, so 0.5 gets rounded up to 1) and an integer "floor" operation on negative values less than one, in which the number gets rounded to the next negative integer (-0.5 gets rounded to -1). See [Floor and ceiling functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) for more details.

I don't know why the program would "suddenly" start treating division this way, but it could have been an update to the libraries that they are using.  You may find some details in their documentation.

Comment: *Face palms.*  I can't believe I didn't see this...  I accidentally "backspaced" too far, and changed a float to an int.  FreePie's script language is based on the Python syntax, so all I need to do is add a ".0" behind a number to "declare" it a float:

"1 / 2.0 = 0.5"  I can't believe I made such a beginner mistake after all this time.  (The reason the whole script appeared to break is because most variables were derived off of that first number which needed to be a float.)  Sorry, I thought the program was bugged, but it was just me all along. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯